# How to pipe input to gsutil cp from stdin?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcloud, gsutil

I am looking for a way to pipe the data into gsutil cp:

```
echo '<html>foobar</html>' | gsutil cp --stdin gs://my-bucket/foo
```

the `-I` option is for reading filepaths, not the data..`gsutil help cp` says:

https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/566d9c3d00e3858c1161ae9b741fc07e

So yeah I am looking for a way to send files to GS via stdin.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like it works using `-` like so:

```
echo '<html>foobar</html>' | gsutil cp - gs://my-bucket/foo
```

in my opinion, a `--stdin` flag would be more explicit and preferred.

Comment: Almost everything in Unix that reads from a file, or writes to a file, accept `-` to mean stdin and stdout respectively. This is consistent with half a century of every single command line tool. So that is to say I disagree with you. :-)

Answer (score -1):

From the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp):

> You can use the -I option with stdin to specify a list of URLs to
> copy, one per line. This allows you to use gsutil in a pipeline to
> upload or download objects as generated by a program:

```
cat filelist | gsutil -m cp -I gs://my-bucket
```

> or:

```
cat filelist | gsutil -m cp -I ./download_dir
```

> where the output of cat filelist is a list of files, cloud URLs, and
> wildcards of files and cloud URLs.